# Implementation of lock free stack using split reference count in the concurrency in action book

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, locking, lock-free

In Anthony williams's Concurrency in action book, he implements lock free stack using split reference count. After the initial load of head node.Here he use method call increase_head_count which is listed in the below code.

```
counted_node_ptr old_head = head.load();
increase_head_count(old_head);

void increase_head_count(counted_node_ptr& old_counter)
{
    counted_node_ptr new_counter;

    do
    {
        new_counter = old_counter;
        ++new_counter.external_count;
    }
    while (!head.compare_exchange_strong(old_counter, new_counter));

    old_counter.external_count = new_counter.external_count;
}
```

full implementation can be found in this link https://github.com/subjam/concurrency-in-action/blob/master/ch7/stack_ref.cpp.

my question is,if a senario occures that more than one thread try to execute pop() concurrently and all threads read head node and then only one executed untill end and others start to execute this fuction afterwards how this implementation works.

I am stuck here for quite some time, I would be really glad if anyone can help me understanding this.

Answer (score 1):

If in the while clause, the old_counter still equals new_counter, then head is set to new_counter.  This is the case for the single thread that succeeds at any one time.

For other threads accessing this method simultaneously, compare_exchange_strong() returns false causing a loop iteration.  However, it will also copy head over the contents of old_counter.

This means in the next loop for these other (unsuccessful) threads, old_counter has been updated with the current contents of head.

Comment: thanks for the answer..i  have few doubts about this..say tow threads come to execute increase_head_count function and one is suspended at the beginning. Now one thread going to execute all the way and even delete the old_node pointer as well (see the full implementation given in the link) now when suspended thread wake up, isn't it going to throw exception (invalid memory or some thing like that ) when executing ++new_counter.external_count; code since it refer deleted node(by first thread).

Comment: The first thread (that goes all the way through method `increase_head_count()` ) will take control of `head` before deleting it.  It attempts to remove it from the stack before deleting.  When it is successfully removed from the stack, the second thread (which wakes up in `increase_head_count()` ) will not have any reference to head.


As I said above, `old_counter` will now be updated to point at the new `head`, so it will not be trying to access any node that has been deleted.

Comment: My concerns with this code would be, if the first (successful) thread gains control of the last pushed node, and `head` now points to the original `counted_node_ptr`, the code (in method `pop`) for this second thread will not attempt to delete this `head`, as `ptr` is `NULL`.  Not deleting the head will allow all secondary threads looping inside `counted_node_ptr` to leave `pop` return an empty value of `T`.  However `ptr` for the original value of `head` is not guaranteed to be `NULL`, as without a constructor it won't have been initialised.